# SWIG reference input, custom class output

Tags: c#, c++, reference, swig

I am trying to work with C++ lib in C# with SWIG.
I have a method which gets float and/or uint8_t reference inputs and returns with a custom class object.
Cannot apply SWIG commands to overcome on this right.

C++:

```
virtual eoReturn GetValue(CHANNEL_TYPE type, float &value) {...}
virtual eoReturn GetValue(CHANNEL_TYPE type, uint8_t &value) {...}
```

.i:

```
%module eoTest
%{  
    #include "eoTest.h"  
%}  

%include typemaps.i
%include cpointer.i 
extern eoReturn eoProfile::GetValue(CHANNEL_TYPE INPUT, float &INPUT);
extern eoReturn eoProfile::GetValue(CHANNEL_TYPE INPUT, uint8_t &INPUT);
%include "eoTest.h"
```

Is still SWIGTYPE_p_float and unsigned_char.
Any idea how to solve this? Or how to initalize a SWIGTYPE_p_float in C#? That also would help I guess.

Answer (score 1):

One solution what found:

added the following to the interface file:

```
%include cpointer.i     
%pointer_functions(float, floatp);
```

This has created methods with names like 'new_floatp', 'delete_floatp', 'floatp_assign'...

Could use in C# like this:

```
SWIGTYPE_p_float f = WrapperCPP.new_floatp();
WrapperCPP.floatp_assign(f, 12);
Console.WriteLine("Value: " + WrapperCPP.floatp_value(f).ToString("0.0")); // Value: 12
WrapperCPP.delete_floatp(f);
```

This would work same for uint8_t too as

```
%pointer_functions(unsigned char, uintp);
```

Hope could help someone too. Cheers